# How to merge ranges from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Giving the following 2 tables:

```
T1
------------------
From | To  | Value
------------------
10   | 20  | XXX
20   | 30  | YYY
30   | 40  | ZZZ


T2
------------------
From | To  | Value
------------------
10   | 15  | AAA
15   | 19  | BBB
19   | 39  | CCC
39   | 40  | DDD
```

What is the best way to get the result below, using T-SQL on SQL Server 2008?

The From/To ranges are sequential (there are no gaps) and the next *From* always has the same value as the previous *To*

```
Desired result
-------------------------------
From | To  | Value1 |  Value2
-------------------------------
10   | 15  | XXX    |  AAA
15   | 19  | XXX    |  BBB
19   | 20  | XXX    |  CCC
20   | 30  | YYY    |  CCC
30   | 39  | ZZZ    |  CCC
39   | 40  | ZZZ    |  DDD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I declare data that looks like the data you posted. Please correct me if any assumptions I have made are wrong. Better would be to post your own declaration in the question so we are all working with the same data.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
  [From] INT,
  [To] INT,
  [Value] CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO @T1 (
  [From],
  [To],
  [Value]
)
VALUES
  (10, 20, 'XXX'),
  (20, 30, 'YYY'),
  (30, 40, 'ZZZ');

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (
  [From] INT,
  [To] INT,
  [Value] CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO @T2 (
  [From],
  [To],
  [Value]
)
VALUES
  (10, 15, 'AAA'),
  (15, 19, 'BBB'),
  (19, 39, 'CCC'),
  (39, 40, 'DDD');
```

Here is my select query to generate your expected result:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN [@T1].[From] > [@T2].[From]
    THEN [@T1].[From]
    ELSE [@T2].[From]
  END AS [From],
  CASE
    WHEN [@T1].[To] < [@T2].[To]
    THEN [@T1].[To]
    ELSE [@T2].[To]
  END AS [To],
  [@T1].[Value],
  [@T2].[Value]
FROM @T1
INNER JOIN @T2 ON
  (
    [@T1].[From] <= [@T2].[From] AND
    [@T1].[To] > [@T2].[From]
  ) OR
  (
    [@T2].[From] <= [@T1].[From] AND
    [@T2].[To] > [@T1].[From]
  );
```

Comment: I removed my comment about the result sets being different, now that they are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Stealing @isme's data setup, I wrote the following:

```
;With EPs as (
    select [From] as EP from @T1
    union
    select [To] from @T1
    union
    select [From] from @T2
    union
    select [To] from @T2
), OrderedEndpoints as (
    select EP,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EP) as rn from EPs
)
select
    oe1.EP,
    oe2.EP,
    t1.Value,
    t2.Value
from
    OrderedEndpoints oe1
        inner join
    OrderedEndpoints oe2
        on
            oe1.rn = oe2.rn - 1
        inner join
    @T1 t1
        on
            oe1.EP < t1.[To] and
            oe2.EP > t1.[From]
        inner join
    @T2 t2
        on
            oe1.EP < t2.[To] and
            oe2.EP > t2.[From]
```

That is, you create a set containing all of the possible end points of periods (`EPs`), then you "sort" those and assign each one a row number (`OrderedEPs`).

Then the final query assembles each "adjacent" pair of rows together, and joins back to the original tables to find which rows from each one overlap the selected range.

Answer (score 0):

The below query finds the smallest ranges, then picks the values back out the tables again:

```
SELECT ranges.from, ranges.to, T1.Value, T2.Value
FROM (SELECT all_from.from, min(all_to.to) as to
    FROM (SELECT T1.FROM
        FROM T1
        UNION 
        SELECT T2.FROM 
        FROM T2) all_from
    JOIN (SELECT T1.TO
        FROM T1
        UNION
        SELECT T2.FROM
        FROM T2) all_to ON all_from.from < all_to.to
    GROUP BY all_from.from) ranges
JOIN T1 ON ranges.from >= T1.from AND ranges.to <= T1.to
JOIN T2 ON ranges.from >= T2.from AND ranges.to <= T2.to
ORDER BY ranges.from
```

Comment: I can't make this query compile. How did you set up your test data?

Comment: This still doesn't compile for me using my data setup. In a copy of your query I replaced all occurrences of `T1` with `[@T1]` and all occurrences of `T2` with `[@T2]`, and received this syntax error on execution: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but I ended using a CTE, wgich I think is cleaner.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE ([From] INT, [To] INT, [Value] CHAR(3));
DECLARE @T2 TABLE ([From] INT, [To] INT, [Value] CHAR(3));

INSERT INTO @T1 (  [From],  [To],  [Value]) VALUES  (10, 20, 'XXX'),  (20, 30, 'YYY'),  (30, 40, 'ZZZ');
INSERT INTO @T2 (  [From],  [To],  [Value]) VALUES  (10, 15, 'AAA'),  (15, 19, 'BBB'),  (19, 39, 'CCC'),  (39, 40, 'DDD');

;with merged1 as 
(
    select 
        t1.[From] as from1,
        t1.[to] as to1,
        t1.Value as Value1,
        t2.[From] as from2,
        t2.[to] as to2,
        t2.Value as Value2
    from @t1 t1
    inner join @T2 t2 
        on t1.[From] <  t2.[To]
        and t1.[To] >= t2.[From]

)
,merged2 as 
(
    select 
          case when from2>=from1 then from2 else from1 end as [From]
         ,case when to2<=to1 then to2 else to1 end as [To]
         ,value1
         ,value2
    from merged1
)
select * from merged2
```